# A man dies because the number is 88 too high

Tags: situation

A man died because the number was 88 too high.

What happened?

Comment: Was he driving a DeLorean at the time?

Comment: No. No time travel was involved.

Comment: Is the 88 some kind of medical measurement (BMI, blood pressure, glucose, etc.)?

Comment: No. No medical measurement of any kind.

Comment: Does it have any associated unit of measurement (miles per hour, gallons, liters, kilograms, seconds, dollars, etc.)?  Or is it just a number?

Comment: No units of measurement of any kind.

Comment: Did the number 88 *guarantee* his death (as opposed to just increasing the risk of it)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37579/discussion-between-matt-cremeens-and-dan04).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic per [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/120/situation-riddles).

Comment: It's surprising to me that there pre-exists a tag for a question that is considered off topic by reason of that same tag (situation).

Comment: @MattCremeens I think the meta post is referring specifically to the type of riddle that requires asking more questions about a situation. If all the information is present in the question already, then there's no problem.

Comment: @f'' The link to the meta post provided mentions situation riddles being inappropriate for this site. Yet, there exists a tag for them. If the question is inappropriate for this site because it is a situation riddle (which is just answered as such in a post, not as a rule) then there should be no tag for situation riddles.

Comment: @Matt: Look at the other ones. All of them are self-contained in the question; the "yes or no question" type is off-topic here.

Comment: @Deusovi All I am saying is that the definition of a situation riddle IS the "yes or no" type. Imagine if we had a tag entitled "riddles in italics" and then someone posted a riddle that was typed in italics, but then someone claimed that riddles typed in italics were off-topic. What's more is that all was offered as evidence that this question was off-topic was a post where two people provided their opinion. Nothing official.

Comment: @Matt: I've seen "situation riddles" defined differently. I agree though - the tag needs to be renamed or possibly deleted altogether. (Also, you'll notice the answer has 9 points - on meta, +1s indicate agreement and -1s indicate disagreement. Anything with a significantly positive score indicates general consensus.)

Comment: @Deusovi I agree with you that the tag should be deleted or redefined IF the official rules of the site indicate that situation riddles should not be allowed. But what is the official stance on closing a topic? Is it a consensus, or at least a preponderance (not sure a handful of users constitutes a consensus or even a preponderance), of users or is it the official rules set by the site creators? Thanks for reminding me on the point system, by the way.

Comment: @Matt: In general, the community decides what is on-topic and what is not. The SE network is for Q&A, though, not discussion - a question should be self-contained on all SE sites, and Puzzling is no exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a series of chat Q&A, dan04 and I figured it out (see the chat discussion for details):

> A British man in the United States was dying, and dialed the only emergency number he knew, which was 999. He didn't realize that the number in the US is actually 911.

Answer (score 6):

Per our discussion in chat:

> A British man was visiting the US when he experienced a life-threatening injury.  He dialed [999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/999_(emergency_telephone_number)) in an attempt to reach an ambulance service, but it didn't work.  Not knowing the US emergency number ([911](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/9-1-1)) but knowing it was three digits, he tried to find it by serial-dialing 998, 997, etc.  But he bled to death before he could get to his 88th attempt.